# How to initialize a JndiTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

I'm sure I'm expecting too much when using the JNDITemplate in Spring Boot, but when I try to bind an object to the JNDI context I get an exception.

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner initJndi() {
    return (args) -> {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.bla.com");
        ... 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        });

        JndiTemplate template = new JndiTemplate();
        template.bind("Session", session); 
    };
}
```

The exception is:

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

The template does not have a JNDI context. But the question is, how is the context to be provided?

**Background**
I want to configure the javax.mail session for a logback smtp appender. The smtp appender is able to use the mail session from JNDI. See [logback SMTPAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) the *sessionViaJNDI* property.

Comment: Why do you need JNDI? If it is only for mail use the Spring mail abstraction then you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because you haven't specified an initial context factory.

Please take a look at some of the providers listed here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/generic.903/a97690/jndi.htm#1005621.

Spring has a `JndiRmiServiceExporter` that makes RMI easy, but I think the choice depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The context factories listed in this document are all made for jee contexts. In a standalone spring boot app they are not useful (no RMI, no ApplicationClient). The other question is how the JNDITemplate learns about this JNDI context.

Comment: If everything is running within the same JVM, then you should be to accomplish this with spring-boot. (example here: https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/jndi/SampleTomcatJndiApplication.java)  If you are trying to host a JNDI resource with a standalone spring-boot application, then any object you use has to be `Serializable`.  From what I can tell `javax.mail.Session` isn't.

Comment: Yes, great! The important part is the enablement of the naming service in the embedded tomcat. Thanks for pointing me to the example! Regarding the serialisability I do not understand why this should be a requirement: there is no use of RMI, everything is within the same process. At least there was no issue with the mail session.

Comment: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.  In regards to serialization, that only mattered if you were trying to host the resource external from your application.  It does not apply to your situation, it seems, so all is good.  Thanks.